# emplace_back a temporary vector in-place to a vector of vector

Tags: c++, vector

suppose we have an array of `int`, and now we want to convert to `vector` of `vector`, in condition that all number less than or equal 5 must be the first element of the sub-vector of the new vector `vv`, and also the length of each sub-vector should no bigger than 3.  //

```
int array[] = {9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 8, 9, 7, 6, 5};
```

and it should be converted to

```
vv = { { 9, 8, 6 }, { 5 }, { 4, 8, 9 }, { 7, 6 }, { 5 } };
```

In order to do that, I can loop through the array and found the elements of the next sub-vector to emplace_back. So that I am considering that after finding the numbers to to pushed back, create temporary vector in-place.

Say, I found 9, 8, 6 goes to the next sub-vector, and 5 goes to next after, we do:

```
vector< vector < int > > vv;
vector < int >  v
v.push_back(9);  
v.push_back(8);  
v.push_back(6);  
vv.push_back(v);
v.clear();
v.push_back(5);
vv.push_back(v)
v.clear();
```

Now vv is { { 9, 8, 6 }, { 5 } }. This is quite cumbersome. Can I have the temporary vector created in-place to emplace_back directly to achieve the same result.

```
vv.emplace_back( vector <int > ( 3, 9, 8, 6 ) ); // this is wrong
vv.emplace_back( vector< int > ( 1, 5 ) );       // this is good.
```

or equivalently,

```
vv.emplace_back( vector <int > { 9, 8, 6 } ); // this is good.
vv.emplace_back( vector< int > ( 1, 5 ) );    // this is good too.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you realize that your edit completely changed your question to something different?

Comment: I made the revision to emphasize that I can not use list initialization when declaring the vector. Do you have better approach for this problem? The method I use is looping through the array, finding the elements for next sub-vector and push in-place.

Comment: "Do you have better approach for this problem?" Which problem? First you described one problem now you have unrelated problem. I may have solution but I am afraid it would suddenly change to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
vector< vector < int > > vv;
...
vv = { { 9, 8, 6 }, { 5 } };
```

or:

```
vector< vector < int > > vv;
...
vv.emplace_back( { 9, 8, 6 } );
vv.emplace_back( { 5 } );
```

you should not create temporary explicitly when calling `emplace_back` method you basically make it equivalent to `push_back`, whole point of `emplace` is to forward parameters to element ctor directly (same for `emplace` methods in other containers).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values in advance you can just do list initialization:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv{
  { 9, 8, 6 }, { 5 }
};
```

Comment: both answers are good, except that in case you do not have the numbers when declaring `vv`.

Comment: @phynju - I think you need to improve your example, to be frank. Create a proper [mcve] you want us to answer about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list initialization:

```
vector<vector<int>> vv{{9,8,6}, {5}};
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/shyin7nIqlwKmlGP)

Comment: both answers are good, except that in case you do not have the numbers when declaring vv.